# Variables in c++ builder XE2 not initializing when unit was called by component

Tags: global-variables, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I have a unit (WebFunctions.h) with the declaration

```
String RawURLAllowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~.-_";
```

This unit works well in the app. But when I add a component which also declares `WebFunctions.h`, the initialization of `RawURLAllowedChars` does not occurs (`RawURLAllowedChars = NULL`).

To get the app back to work, plus remove the class declaration of the component is still necessary delete the `WebFunctions.obj` file.

Note: Any declarations in `.cpp` file, with or without a `extern` declaration in `.h` file, also are not working.

This is a bug in XE2 or I'm missing something? Thanks.

Obs.: Var declarations inside `#ifndef .. #endif`

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize a global variable in a header file.  Declare the variable as `extern` in the .h file and then initialize it in the corresponding .cpp file, eg:

WebFunctions.h:

```
extern const String RawURLAllowedChars;
```

WebFunctions.cpp:

```
const String RawURLAllowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~.-_";
```

Comment: Initially there are in this way, this not working too. I have trying the two ways by now without success. Without the component, both declarations (in .h file and in .cpp file with extern in .h file) works. There are some variables too that are private and declared only in .cpp, not working like the others.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a real solution... but...

Comment (in the .cpp file of main app) the line with **#pragma link "Component"**, added with the component which uses WebFunctions.h (not initializing unit).

Delete all building files in Debug\Win32 folder.

Recompile the App.