# Global class instance constructor not called

Tags: c++, class, constructor, global

```
Meta.h

class TMeta
{
   // decs here
   TMeta()
   {
      // initialisations
   }
};
extern TMeta Meta;
---------------------------

Meta.cpp

TMeta Meta;

// TMeta fct bodies here
---------------------------
```

With the above setup I expected to be able to access Meta from any other .cpp file that included Meta.h. In my main form (which inludes Meta.h) I click on a button which calls Meta.SomeMetaFct(). When the debugger enters this function I find variables that should have been initialised in the Meta constructor haven't been touched.

I thought all global variables were initialised before the main program executed. Is this not the case with global class variables or am I missing something? I did look up some similar questions but I'm none the wiser.

Edit: I'm puzzled as to how Meta seems to exist yet has not been constructed???

Answer: A compiler warning I received today suggested it was using a no longer valid meta.obj file so finally got it working after doing a cleanup and build. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: I'm using Embarcadero C++ builder 10.1 Berlin but not sure what compiler they use.

Comment: There appear to be issues with that, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095768/variables-in-c-builder-xe2-not-initializing-when-unit-was-called-by-component

Comment: Only way I can get it to work is to move theTMeta Meta; line to the main form .cpp file.

Comment: Add a `printf("ctor called");` inside TMeta's constructor. It may be the case that the constructor runs but something else fiddles with the object.

Comment: I've got a breakpoint in the constructor Nikola but it's never hit with the original setup. It does stop there if I move the TMeta Meta; line to the main form though.